# I can't make even the most basic job jar file for Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a uni assignment that requires me to use Apache Flink with very little guidance. I studied a few examples of code and got a pretty good idea about how to write the source code. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to successfully compile it. I copied an example off of YouTube just to see if I can get it to work, and I've solved many errors on the way but I am completely stumped now.

I basically try to upload a basic jar file, having *hacked* together all of the dependencies from various sourced, due to lack of a comprehensive guide on how to set it all up, and I upload it through the dashboard on `localhost`. I made sure to specify the entry point (took me a while to figure out), but in the end I get an error that I have no idea how to fix.

I copied the Job Manager's Log into a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AQvGCnGi), because I figured that it would contain useful information, and I really don't know how to trim that information down to something useful.

I've noticed that the log complains about the `print()` function *(eager execution function*, at line 145, so I tried reuploading the jar file, this time removing the `print()`, and I get a different error, saying:

`2022-01-07 17:15:56,391 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler   [] - Exception occurred in REST handler: No jobs included in application.`

I've included the entirety of the second log in this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ciFTv0jF), but feel free to give me advice based solely on the first, I'm only posting the second one in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best examples you can find in flink-examples in the Flink report. Have you taken a look at https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/wordcount/WordCount.java ?

Comment: My problem isn't that I don't know how to write code for flink. It's that I get lost in the mess of dependencies and Maven and whatnot. I have seen the source code for the example and I understand how it works, but even if I copy and paste it I can't for the life of me figure out how to correctly compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions for the [maven quickstart](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/#maven-quickstart) is the best way to create a basic maven project for getting started with Flink.

For a more complete example project that uses maven, I can suggest [this repo](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/flink-mobile-data-usage) and its associated [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCP9-HdId9w).

There are more examples (using gradle) in the [Flink training exercises](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/).